# EXCEL VBA - pass each selected cell range to macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to have the user select cells in a worksheet they want to work with, (non congruent cells), then click an icon in the ribbon that does blah blah blah to those cell.

How do I pass just the cells they selected as a range into my macro?

Comment: You can use `Selection`

Comment: `For Each cell In Selection`